# Google Cloud Datalab - how to create a VM for training using by multiple users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, data-science, training-data, google-cloud-datalab

I am new with Datalab, our team of data scientist asked us to have 5 individual VM for each of them, and another VM for Training which should be accessed by any of them. I have searched a lot and in documents of google it is written:

> “Cloud Datalab instances are single-user environments, therefore each member of your team needs their own instance.”

So, my question is, what is the best practice for having a training Datalab machine and how I can give access to it to multiple users?

Comment: As you could read [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/datalab-team), such feature is not supported. Each user must have their own Datalab instance

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around:

1) create a G Suite [Group](http://groups.google.com) in your organization, each group has an email address which can be used to give access in Google Cloud

2) add users to the group

3) add group's email address to IAM and give the following access: ***compute.instanceAdmin.v1*** and ***iam.serviceAccountActor***

4) create datalab VM and for the option **--for-user** put the email address of the group

5) Users now can conncet to the VM from their cloud shell using the following command:

```
datalab connect <VM_NAME> --no-user-checking
```

So,each user has its own VM to develop and push the codes on repository, and for training, they can connect to this VM but not in the same time.